# iptables-save return with errno 1 - operation not permited

Tags: linux, iptables

When I run the command

```
iptables-save
```

it returns with errno 1 - opearation not permitted

If I do:

```
iptables -L
```

and then:

```
iptables-save
```

then iptables-save succeeds

This error happens only once. After it succeeds the failure disappears.

I am writing a script which deploys iptables on my hosts and I have to recover from this error automatically, any suggestions?

I also noticed that when I do:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables status
```

I get:

```
Firewall is stopped.
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the iptables modules are not loaded in your kernel before you run the first command. What does `lsmod | grep ipt` show?

Comment: yes you are right lsmod does not show iptables which means iptables is not loaded. how can I load it?

Comment: What distribution are we talking about?

Comment: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)

Comment: You can either `modprobe iptable_filter` or `chkconfig iptables on` IIRC.

Comment: @fukawi2 I think this is a fairly subtle and sophisticated point you've uncovered here.  To me, this is a worthy question, and yours the right answer.  Any chance you'd write it up as a full answer?

Comment: it worked for me. thanks a lot. please write it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is usually seen when the relevant kernel modules have not been loaded. Running `iptables -L` will implicitly load the modules, but `iptables-save` won't.

You can confirm this by running `lsmod | grep ipt` -- if you don't get any output then the modules are not loaded.

You can manually load the modules (for this boot only) by running `modprobe iptable_filter` or enable the iptables service to load the modules at each boot: `chkconfig iptables on` (assuming you're running RedHat-family distro).